# Errors while using a laravel 5 boilerplate

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I want to use
https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-5-boilerplate as a starting point for my Laravel project, but when I do `composer install` i get the following errors.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for guzzle/guzzle v3.9.3 -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.9.3].
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.9.3 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for stripe/stripe-php v1.18.0 -> satisfiable by stripe/stripe-php[v1.18.0].
    - stripe/stripe-php v1.18.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
  Problem 3
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.9.3 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - league/oauth1-client 1.5.0 requires guzzle/guzzle 3.* -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.9.3].
    - Installation request for league/oauth1-client 1.5.0 -> satisfiable by league/oauth1-client[1.5.0].
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are missing `php5-curl - CURL module for php5`

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

and try to install again.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using ubuntu 16.04, by default it comes with php 7. you are missing php-curl - CURL module for php7

```
  sudo apt install php-curl
```